# androidx AppBarLayout AppBar top margin problem

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appbarlayout, androidx, appbar

Why is the AppBar going up? And how to fix it?

Additional Information.

If you start the activity and then immediately this fragment, then everything is OK.

If you start the activity and then some fragment and then this fragment, then everything is bad.

[image]

[image. Android Studio layout designer - OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo3iO.png)

[image. API 16 - OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDIYF.png)

The xml layout [code is here.](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/tim4dev/oe5zKB)

**UPD.**

```
<style name="EcommerceToolbar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar">
        <item name="android:theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Are you able to share `@style/EcommerceToolbar`?

Comment: @es0329 see UPD please.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the attribute `layout_height` to `"?attr/actionBarSize"` from your `AppBarLayout`:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
       android:id="@+id/filter_list_appbar_layout"
       app:liftOnScroll="false"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       >
```

Answer (score 0):

It `s Magic.
Create (v21) styles and add there:

```
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```